# Can't increment mergeinfo count ... to negative value 

Tags: svn

I have a problem with my subversion repository. I'm currently not able to do copy operations on the repository.

If I try to copy a part of the repository to a new folder in the repository I get the following error

> [Wed Nov 03 10:50:42 2010] [error] [client 10.10.62.5] Could not MOVE/COPY /svn/Server/!svn/bc/41280/trunk. [500, #0]
>
> [Wed Nov 03 10:50:42 2010] [error] [client 10.10.62.5] Unable to make a filesystem copy. [500, #160004]
>
> [Wed Nov 03 10:50:42 2010] [error] [client 10.10.62.5] Can't increment mergeinfo count on node-revision 0.0.t41280-ub6 to negative value -8520666390062167758 [500, #160004]

Can anybody tell me what the cause of this error message is and what I can do to resolve it?

Regards
Bosco

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some data corruption. Do a `svnadmin verify` on the server and check the health of your server disk.

**edit**: The error code associated with the error message in the SVN source code is SVN_ERR_FS_CORRUPT, so I'm pretty sure there is data corruption in your repository. The fact that `svnadmin verify` does not detect this is most likely a bug which you should report at http://subversion.apache.org/. But first make sure that you still have these issues (both the original problem and the fact that `svnadmin verify` does not report errors) after installing the latest version of SVN on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've already done the verification. It results in no error.
The strange thing is that I can commit, merge and do every other operation on the repository. The only thing that doesn't work is doing a copy operation.